# Adding two javascript functions

Tags: javascript, html

Hey guys, i have a javascript function which tallys up the rel value of checkboxes and displays the answer, I now have a `<select>` statement with 3 values. Each value has a different fiscal value i.e 40,50 & 60. I cant figure out a java statement that will add the fiscal value of my select statement selection(tong twister) and add it to my existing java function below.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        function recalculate() {
            var sum = 0;

            $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
                 sum += parseInt($(this).attr("rel"));
            });

            $("#output").html(sum);
        }

        $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
            recalculate();
        });

    });




   <td width="236" height="25" align="left">Booking Duration: </td>
    <td width="548" height="23"><select name="duration" id="duration1">
    <option value="One Day" id="one" rel="40">One Day</option>
    <option value="Two Day" id="two" rel="50">Two Day</option>
    <option value="Weekend" id="weekend" rel="60">Weekend</option>
    </select>
```

The output of my initial function is displayed here `<span id="output"></span>`

How do I go about writing a second java that adds the rel value of my select statement with the sum value of my initial javascript function.

Sorry I dont think i made my question clear. I already have a series of checkboxes which the above code adds up the rel values of the checked check boxes and displays. I now ALSO have a select statement with three options each which have a relf value. I now want to write some code that adds the rel values of the checkboxes AND that of the select statement.

Comment: You need to be clearer with your question.  What have you tried, what is the output, and what is your desired output.

Comment: i thought i was being clear, sorry mate. I just have no idea how to go about writing a java function which adds the rel values of the select options and the sum value of the javascript function above

Comment: First note: **NEVER USE parseInt WITHOUT A RADIX ARGUMENT**.

Comment: Can you post all your HTML, with the checkboxes?  Is that all your code?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the 'value' property of the option elements to contain the number rather than the 'rel'. Jquery (which it looks like you're using) can fetch that property using the .val() function, or you can use vanilla Javascript to do it. Once you've fetched the value, you can do what you like with it.

You could store the result of the original function in a global variable that the second function can access - that's one way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem resides in your HTML, you are talking about "checkboxes" and you consider so in your javascript, BUT your HTML displays a SELECT ..

What about this for your HTML

```
<td width="236" height="25" align="left">Booking Duration: </td>
<td width="548" height="23">
<input type="checkbox" name="duration" id ="one" value="One" /> One
<input type="checkbox" name="duration" id ="two" value="Two" /> Two
<input type="checkbox" name="duration" id ="weekend" value="Weekend" /> Weekend
```